# php imap functions download corrupt files

Tags: php, email, imap

Im have successfully created a php script that downloads specific email attachment ot my server.

However, they all appear corrupt. (Correct files names downloaded but 0 KB file size on server)

**Here is my code I use for download:**

```
/* iterate through each attachment and save it */
foreach($attachments as $attachment){

  if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
  {
    $filename = $attachment['name'];
    if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

    if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

    /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
       * have the attachment with the same file name.
    */
    $converted = utf8_decode(iconv_mime_decode($filename));
    $text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/', '_', $converted);

    $fp = fopen("att/".$text, "w+");
    fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
    fclose($fp);
  }
}
```

The regular expression before the save function converts the special chars that often appear in attachment files.

What could I improve here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the following line...

```
$converted = utf8_decode(iconv_mime_decode($filename));
```

The iconv_mime_decode function decodes headers. You are passing in a filename. You need to load the file contents then pass the contents into that function.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$converted = utf8_decode(iconv_mime_decode($contents));
```

Comment: thanks for answer, not sure what you mean exactly...I think this messes up the file name...

Comment: Basically iconv_mime_decode decodes the contents of the file. You are giving it the file name. You need to read the file and give it the contents, not the filename.

Comment: the attachement contents are actually not the in $filename but in the line fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']); ...so this line is problematic I think